# Creating new dictionary with subset data from another dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with two keys `image` and `label`. `image` is a numpy array of image pixels and `label` is the corresponding label of the image (integer between 0 to 9).
I'm trying to create a new dictionary with only certain data from the original, with only 50 images from each label.

My intuition says that there is an easy way to do this, but the only way I can think of now is doing multiple for loops.

Creating the original dictionary:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import jax.numpy as jnp

ds_builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
ds_builder.download_and_prepare()

train_ds = tfds.as_numpy(ds_builder.as_dataset(split='train', batch_size=-1))
# Convert to floating-points
train_ds['image'] = jnp.float32(train_ds['image']) / 255.0
```

And what I want is a new `train_ds2` dictionary with only 50 images for each of the 10 labels in `train_ds`

EDIT:

I'm adding my attempt (although I think there must be a better way):

```
t_im = np.zeros((500,28,28,1))
t_lbl = np.zeros(500)

for k in tqdm(range(10)):
  while i < 50:
    for j in range(len(train_ds['label'])):
      if train_ds['label'][j] == k:
        t_im[k*50 + i,:,:,:] = train_ds['image'][j,:,:,:]
        t_lbl[k*50 + i] = train_ds['label'][j]
    i += 1
```

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`train_ds['image']` and `train_ds['label']` both are instance of `jaxlib.xla_extension.DeviceArray`. You can slice them as follow:

```py
import random
import jax.numpy as jnp

idx = jnp.array(random.sample(range(len(train_ds['image'])), 50))

train_ds['image'][:50] # Get 50 items from start
train_ds['image'][idx] # Get arbitrary 50 items
```

So to create a new dictionary, you only need to do something like

```py
train_df_part = {
    'image': train_ds['image'][:50],
    'label': train_ds['label'][:50]
}
```